# Getting AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute '_jdf in pyspark'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to implement Gradient boosting algorithm on a kaggle dataset in pyspark for learning purpose. I am facing  error given below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/SparkCourse/Gradientboost.py", line 29, in <module>
    output=assembler.transform(data)
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\ml\base.py", line 105, in transform
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py", line 281, in _transform
AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

the corresponding code is

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer,VectorIndexer,OneHotEncoder,VectorAssembler





spark=SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp").appName("Gradientboostapp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
data= spark.read.csv("C:/Users/codemen/Desktop/Timeseries Analytics/liver_patient.csv",header=True, inferSchema=True)
#data.show()
print(data.count())
#data.printSchema()
print("After deleting  null  values")

data=data.na.drop()
print(data.count())

data=StringIndexer(inputCol="Gender",outputCol="GenderIndex").fit(data)


#let onehot encode the data

data=OneHotEncoder(inputCol="GenderIndex",outputCol="gendervec")


usedfeature=["Age","gendervec","Total_Bilirubin","Direct_Bilirubin","Alkaline_Phosphotase","Alamine_Aminotransferase","Aspartate_Aminotransferase","Total_Protiens","Albumin","Albumin_and_Globulin_Ratio"]
#
assembler=VectorAssembler(inputCols=usedfeature,outputCol="features")
output=assembler.transform(data)
output.select("features","category").show()
```

I have converted  Gender category into numerical form by using String indexer then I have tried to perform OnehotEncoding on Genderindex value. I am getting the error when I have performed VectorAssembler in code. May I am missing very silly concept here. kindly help me to figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code is incorrect: `data=OneHotEncoder(inputCol="GenderIndex",outputCol="gendervec")`.  You are setting `data` to be equal to the `OneHotEncoder()` object, not transforming the data.  You need to call a `transform` to encode the data.  It should look like this.

`encoder=OneHotEncoder(inputCol="GenderIndex",outputCol="gendervec")
data = encoder.transform(data)`